# Can I skin Flex 4 Spark UI components with runtime CSS?

Tags: flex4

Can I skin Flex 4 Spark UI components with runtime CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the Skin. Some default spark skins support a couple of CSS properties. However there are significantly less properties available as for Halo components.

In general I would consider CSS skinning as obsolete since the Spark skinning with FXG is much more powerful and easier. You can switch the entire skin at runtime or better: Write a custom skin that is displayed differently based on the SkinState of your component.